# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer (Python)

Tags: python

I have a problem in the following code what happens is that insert, in an array a string and an integer, at the time of starting the code I get the following error.

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This error comes from the line where the IF and insert the two variables in the array noRepetidos, how can I fix this? Thank you very much to everyone who can help me.

```
for i in range (len(carta3)):
 for j in range (len(carta3[i])):
  counted = Counter([item for sublist in carta3 for item in sublist])
  a = counted.get(carta3[i][j])
   if(carta[i][j] in noRepetidos) == False:
    repetidos.insert(carta[i][j], int(a))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Questions here do need to be in English: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: It might be that the order of arguments has to be changed in the last line (`repetidos.insert(int(a), carta[i][j])` - and perhaps `a` is number already), but next time show some minimal set of variables too, code snippets are expected to be runnable without guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola

It looks like you want to show the duplicate in a nested list? Try this:

```
counter = Counter([
    item for sublist in carta3 for item in sublist
])
repetidos = [
    (key, count) for key, count in counter.most_common()
    if count > 1
]
```

Chio

Comment: It is what I needed, so many thanks bro